# How to use L-308 or L-758 in a dark room to get the exposure time of the printed photos?

Tags: printing, darkroom, light-meter, enlarging

I have a sekonic L-308B and a L-758C .
Can I get the exposure time ?
How
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not reasonably possible to do it.  The Gossen Profisix has a lab attachment but even that doesn't give accurate readings for prints. You need a dedicated meter for enlargers.  They are expensive.  Or, you can do what we have always done.   Make teststrips.

Comment: Since you are advising to use the time honored method of test strips, Perhaps you could explain what a test strip is and how they are used to determine proper exposure for printing in a dark room; for those that may not know and stumble across this question seeking detailed and informative answers.

Comment: Thanks.      I am considering using a simple illuminance meter.   Illuminometer will tell the "Lux" ..